# Reading separate components of 8.3 filename into proper filename in C

Tags: c

I need to read an archive file format which stores filenames as 8 characters for the name (null-terminated if less than 8 characters, not otherwise), immediately followed by 3 characters for the extension (i.e. without a dot). So basically, I need to read the components and add a dot between the name and extension (name.ext).

Is this the way to go, or is there a better/more common way of doing it?

```
#include <stdio.h>  // (f)printf, fopen, fseek, ftell, fread, fclose
#include <stdlib.h> // calloc, free

void read_filename(FILE *arc, char *filename)
{
    // read file name
    if(8 != fread(&filename[0], 1, 8, arc))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed reading file name at 0x%08X\n", ftell(arc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // find the "real" end of the name and append a dot
    int c;
    for(c=0; c < 8 && filename[c] != '\0'; c++);
    filename[c] = '.';

    // read extension into the offset of the dot + 1
    if(3 != fread(&filename[c+1], 1, 3, arc))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed reading file extension at 0x%08X\n", ftell(arc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) return 1;

    // open the archive
    FILE *arc = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if(arc==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not open file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // seek to 0x28, which is the offset of the first filename
    fseek(arc, 0x28, SEEK_SET);

    // allocate cleared memory for the file name
    char *filename = (char *)calloc(12, 1);

    // read the file name into the memory block allocated
    read_filename(arc, filename);

    printf("First filename: %s...", filename);

    free(filename);
    fclose(arc);

    return 0;
}
```

An example of a filename might look like this (hex dump):

```
0x00000028   46 49 4C 45 4E 41 4D 00 65 78 74 00   FILENAM ext
```

the space in the example above is a null byte.

or it can look like this:

```
0x00000028   46 49 4C 45 4E 41 4D 45 65 78 74 00   FILENAMEext
```

in this example there is no null terminator for the name -- as mentioned before, the extension always immediately follows the first 8 bytes.

Comment: Partial code is hard to review, people can't know if it is even working code. Can you provide the rest? At least the whole function where this snippet belongs?

Comment: Also, a small sample of the expected input data would be very nice!

Comment: @glampert actually there isn't a whole lot more to it. But you're right maybe a few more details would help; please have a look at the revised code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Avoid "tricky" loops

There is nothing technically wrong with this line:

```
for(c=0; c < 8 && filename[c] != '\0'; c++);
```

However, because one doesn't usually write a `for` loop with no body, it would probably be useful for your code to call attention to the fact that there's nothing happening within the loop.  You could write it like this:

```
for(c=0; c < 8 && filename[c] != '\0'; c++) {
    // do nothing 
}
```

Or another way:

```
for(c=0; c < 8 && filename[c] != '\0'; c++)
    continue;
```

All will likely compile to the exact same object code.

### Don't mix I/O with data operations

Generally speaking having a `printf` within a data manipulation function such as `read_filename` is not a good idea.  It makes it harder to reuse the function.  It's OK for diagnostics and for troubleshooting, but it would be better to omit it from the final version.  Similarly, it would be better if the `fread` would read the entire 8.3 filename into a memory buffer and then pass the memory buffer to code that would do the parsing.  That cleanly separates I/O from data manipulation and is probably more efficient as well.

### Return an error code

The `read_filename` function can detect errors, but summarily exits the entire program rather than returning an error code that would allow the calling function to decide how to handle the error. A more robust design that might allow the code to be reused would return an error code.

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

Things like `if (argc != 2)` are OK, because programmers reading this will know what that code is doing.  However, when you write `if(8 != fread(&filename[0], 1, 8, arc))` it's not at all obvious whether 8 is the correct value, or exactly what it represents.  Better would be to use a named `const` value there such as `const size_t FILENAMESIZE = 8;`

### Be careful with assumptions about argument size

In the `fprintf` functions, the parameter should be `0x%08lX` rather than `0x%08X` because `ftell()` returns a `long`.

### Try this

Here's one way to do this, incorporating all of these suggestions:

```
// max size of 8.3 filename
const size_t FILENAMELEN = 11u;
const size_t EXTOFFSET = 8u;
const size_t EXTLEN = 3u;

char *read_filename(FILE *arc)
{
    char *filename = malloc(FILENAMELEN+2);
    if (filename == NULL) {
        return filename;
    }
    filename[FILENAMELEN] = '\0';
    if (FILENAMELEN != fread(filename, 1u, FILENAMELEN, arc)) {
        free(filename);
        return NULL;
    }
    return filename;
}

char *parse_filename(char *filename)
{
    if (filename == NULL) {
        return filename;
    }
    // insert the '.'
    memmove(&filename[EXTOFFSET+1], &filename[EXTOFFSET], EXTLEN);
    filename[EXTOFFSET] = '.';
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; filename[i] && i < EXTOFFSET; ++i) {
    }
    if (i < EXTOFFSET) {
        memmove(&filename[i], &filename[EXTOFFSET], EXTLEN+2);
    }
    return filename;
}
```

Comment: "it would be better if the `fread` would read the entire 8.3 filename into a memory buffer and then pass the memory buffer to code that would do the parsing. That cleanly separates I/O from data manipulation and is probably more efficient as well." Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: @user966939: I've updated my answer to show exactly how one might use a single `fread`.

Comment: Why `FILENAMELEN+2`?  If it's so that `parse_filename` has room to insert a dot in certain cases, then these processes aren't quite as discrete as you're making them out to be.  (Passing a string that didn't come from `read_filename` runs the risk of using unallocated space.)  Perhaps `parse_filename` should be less afraid to call `realloc`.

Comment: @cHao: Good point; one could also recombine the two (which was how I posted the code in the first version before the recent edit).  As for `realloc`, I considered it but thought that the overhead of that call was probably not worth the few bytes saved. It's an option, though, if memory is tight.

Comment: @Edward is it worth it re-inventing the wheel to avoid including additional headers for memmove (string.h)? It's a simple for-loop: `for (;size;size--) buf[offset+size] = buf[(offset+size)-1];`

Comment: @user966939: you need more than a simple `for` loop because the data areas may overlap.

Comment: @Edward Accepted your answer. I realized one thing though; would it not be best to check if memory was properly allocated after calling c/malloc (`var!=NULL`)? I didn't check for it in my own code either...

Comment: @user966939:  Yes, you should *absolutely* check to make sure that `malloc` doesn't return `NULL`.  Good catch and shame on me!  I've fixed the code in my answer.

Comment: @Edward I came up with a different approach! What do you think of this? http://pastie.org/private/p0gwczl0r1ivapmllxgvw (sorry for external link, eh). Any reason not to use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20386/discussion-between-edward-and-user966939).

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after accepting Edward's answer, I came up with a different approach for the filename parsing:

```
if (filename[7])
    sprintf(&filename[8], ".%c%c%c", filename[8], filename[9], filename[10]);
else
    sprintf(&filename[0], "%s.%s", &filename[0], &filename[8]);
```

This works because the length of the name within the file format are always exactly 8 bytes, and the extension is always exactly 3 bytes. Both are padded with null bytes to the right if less than 8 or 3 "actual" characters, respectively.

Comment: Nice answer! Very elegant approach.  You might consider using `snprintf` for safety, though.